# Fullcalendar.js: Add "save as pdf" button to save the calendar in a pdf format

Tags: jquery

does anyone here know how to put "Save as PDF" button on jquery fullcalendar? I would like my calendar to save in pdf file so I can sent it through email. Thanks

Comment: I have same request. Can anyone helped ?

Comment: I had same issue. I used html2canvas for create image of calendar. Then put the image into pdf with tcpdf library. And last, I used phpmailer for sent email with attacment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jspdf](https://code.google.com/p/jspdf/), but more complex graphics could be a problem, so this is only a solution if you want to convert text into pdf.

For more complex PDFs, you're bound to use something server side (or rely on the user having installed a Print-To-Pdf program). Since you didn't specify what your server is, it's hard to suggest something.

Comment: How can I use that to my calendar page? Sorry I'm really new to jquery.. I just want to put a button that will print or save the calendar as an image or pdf.. Can you help me how to implement this one? thanks..